# Code Igniter insert MySQL function with database class

Tags: database, class, codeigniter

I got the data , that are going to be saved into my database using the CI's database class:

```
$data = array(
    'login' => $this->input->post('login', TRUE),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password', TRUE),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE)
);

return $this->db->insert('account', $data);
```

Now I need to use the MySQL function `PASSWORD()` to get the `password` post hash.

I've tried this way:

`'password' => "PASSWORD(" . $this->input->post('password', TRUE) . ");`

But CI's database class convert it to the following string:

```
INSERT INTO `accounts` [..] 'PASSWORD("mypassword")'
```

so as you can see, it won't work since it will save the whole string between `'`.

Is there any solution for this or I'd have to use the `$this->db->query` ?

Comment: A simple alternative is to use CI's MD5 option. `$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[passconf]|md5');`

Comment: yes, I know but using `md5` these times is a little bit unsafe, since there are already a thousands of sites with `md5` hashes library, and hacker can decode some hashes easy.

Comment: I strongly recommend **NOT** to use any md5 hashes for passwords anywhere!

Comment: @bottleboot , thats why I told BozKay its unsafe and I want to use MySQL's `PASSWORD()` function instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `set()` method to set your INSERT values, and then pass a third parameter (`FALSE`) to prevent CodeIgniter from escaping `PASSWORD`. Something like this:

```
$this->db->set('login', $this->input->post('login', TRUE));
$this->db->set('password', 'PASSWORD("'.$this->input->post('password', TRUE).'")', FALSE);
$this->db->set('email', $this->input->post('email', TRUE));

return $this->db->insert('account');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to escape the password !
You disable escaping for the password with Colin's solution.
You could use **$this->db->escape** to escape it
example for possible injection:

```
$injection = '"), "malicious data" #")';
echo 'PASSWORD("'.$injection.'")';
```

I hope I got this right.